# proxy-like python module

Tags: python

Can a python module hand over other module in case of self being imported?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of do it (in the normal CPython anyway):

```
# uglyhack.py

import sys
import othermodule

sys.modules[__name__]= othermodule
```

then:

```
>>> import uglyhack
>>> uglyhack
<module 'othermodule' from '...'>
```

This relies on the assignment of the global for the module in the importing script/module happening after the body of imported module has finished executing, so by the time the import assignment happens, the `sys.modules` lookup has been sabotaged to point at another module.

I wouldn't use this in proper code for anything other than (maybe) debugging. There should almost always be a better way for whatever it is you're up to.

Comment: Shouldn't the `sys.__modules__` in the first code snippet be `sys.modules`? Or is that for some Python version older than 2.6.6?

Answer (score 0):

```
import other_module
for name in dir(other_module):
    globals()[name] = getattr(other_module, name)
del other_module
```

Comment: This will break if other_module has an attribute called other_module. You can add a special case for that if you need to.